# Le verbe de parole "lancer": quelles différences avec les verbes plus neutres comme "dire" ou "demander"?

Tags: verbes, stylistique

Il m'arrive de trouver de plus en plus souvent dans les livres français contemporains le verbe de parole «lancer». Le dictionnaire Larousse donne comme définition :

> Dire quelque chose de manière soudaine, inattendue ou de manière assez violente : ex. Lancer une plaisanterie. Lancer des insultes.

J’ai cependant l’impression que le verbe est employé tout simplement pour varier les verbes de parole classiques, comme *dire* ou *demander*, par exemple. A-t-il une signification différente, une nuance qui le différencie des autres verbes de parole ? Est-il plus brusque ?
Je copie ici quelques exemples tirés d’un roman contemporain.

1. «L’assaillant est souvent quelqu’un qu’on connaît», lance la cheffe.
   «La plupart du temps, c’est un membre de la famille, un oncle, un
   cousin.»
2. «Reposez-vous !» lance l’infirmière en guise de conclusion,
   en l’abandonnant dans son lit.
3. Son interlocutrice la dévisage, avant
   de désigner le récipient en train de chauffer. «Je fais du thé, t’en
   veux ?» lance‐t‐elle.

Dans l’exemple n. 2 le ton semble plus brusque, mais dans les deux autres il me semble neutre.

Comment: Selon le Larousse, cela n'est pas le cas,. Alors, pourquoi ne pas accepter la définition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'emploi du verbe lancer au sens figuré n'est pas un emploi contemporain.
Le plus ancien exemple donné dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lancer) date du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle : *Je lance ma parole comme un foudre bruyant* (Robert Garnier).

Par rapport à dire ou demander (quand il s'agit d'une question) l'emploi de lancer n'est pas neutre. Il indique la façon dont le locuteur émet la parole, donnant ainsi l'avis que porte sur ce locuteur la personne à laquelle il s'adresse, ou, selon le contexte, le narrateur.

Exemple 1 : C'est la cheffe qui parle, une cheffe ça commande, ça dirige, il est normal qu'elle parle de façon très directe et sans ménagement.

Exemple 2 : L'infirmière est excédée face à une malade qui proteste, pour clore la conversation elle abandonne sa patiente en lui disant de façon brusque de se reposer.

Exemple 3 : la personne qui émet ces paroles est qualifiée quelques ligne plus haut de « meneuse ». Une meneuse c'est par essence quelqu'un d'autoritaire, le ton est sec.

Ces trois exemples étant tirés du même roman contemporain (*Le cerf-volant*, Laetitia Colombani), il est possible que l'auteure aime particulièrement ce verbe, mais dans les trois exemples donnés son emploi est tout à fait conforme à l'emploi habituel.

[Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/lancer) :

> au figuré : Envoyer sans ménagement à l'adresse de qqn. Lancer des accusations.

[TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lancer)

> Dire avec force.
> a) Dire soudainement et avec vivacité.

Comment: La réponse est très claire, merci !